# Es ist richtig diese Abkürzung in "umgangsprachlich"?

Tags: grammatical-case, colloquial

in "umgangssprachlich" die satz - ich nehme das für morgen- wird " ich nehm's für morgen"  und ich habe das verstanden..

Jetzt, meine frage ist:

kann ich die abkzürgung auch mit jeden andere konjugationen verwenden? ich meine:

ich nehm's

du nimmst's

Er/es/die nimmt's

wir nehmen's (Oder wir nehm's?? )

ihr nehmt's

sie/Sie nehmen's (Oder sie/Sie nehm's??)

vielen danke in voraus, ich warte auf dich, das ist für mich wichtig, wircklick wichtig..

Comment: Ja, das kann man.

Comment: Oh, vielen danke,  also ausgezeichnet! Lezte zwei fragen: 1) also, kann ich diese Abkürzung mit jeden verb (wenn es die richtige fälle gibt) zum beispiele:" ist's richtig?" 2) wenn es eine nebensatz gibt, kann ich die Abkürzung so benutzen? -> " ich bin froh Weil ich gemacht hab's ( ich bin froh Weil ich das gemacht habe) ich warte auf dich

Comment: Nein, das letzte Beispiel ist falsch. Man kann darf dabei die Satzstellung nicht verändern. Aber "Ich bin froh weil ich's gemacht habe" geht.  "Ist's richtig?" kann man sagen, aber das hört man nicht häufig, da man in diesem Fall eher "Ist das richtig?" und nicht "Ist es richtig?" fragt (wofür die Abkürzung ja stünde).

Comment: Und.. kann man imperativ mit diese Abkürzung machen? Zum beispiel:  mach's ! (Mach das!) ?

Comment: Das ist wircklick die lezte..

Comment: Ja, das geht auch: "Rede nicht lange und mach's einfach!" ist ein üblicher Satz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ja, umgangssprachlich ist das moeglich. Das **'s** ist eher die Abkuerzung fuer **es** nicht **das**, aber das macht wohl keinen Unterschied hier.

Ich nehme es. --> Ich nehm's

Du nimmst es. --> Du nimmst's.

Er/Sie/Es nimmt es. --> Er/Sie/Es nimmt's.

Wir nehmen es. --> Wir nehmen's.

Ihr nehmt es. --> Ihr nehmt's.

Sie nehmen es. --> Sie nehmen's.

Es ist moeglich, dass in bestimmten Dialekten "nehm's" im Plural oder andere Varianten vorkommen. Das weiss ich nicht.

EDIT: Wo ich nun darueber nachdenke, faellt mir auf, dass ich tatsaechlich "Wir nehm's" oder "Sie nehm's" verwenden wuerde. Es ist wohl kein Dialekt, sondern lediglich Bequemlichkeit.

Comment: 1) also, kann ich diese Abkürzung mit jeden verb (wenn es die richtige fälle gibt) zum beispiele:" ist's richtig?" 2) wenn es eine nebensatz gibt, kann ich die Abkürzung so benutzen? -> " ich bin froh Weil ich gemacht hab's ( ich bin froh Weil ich das gemacht habe) ich warte auf dich

Comment: **'s** ersetzt **es**, also "Ich bin froh, weil ich **es** gemacht habe." ---> "Ich bin froh, weil **ich's** gemacht habe."

Comment: Und.. kann man imperativ mit diese Abkürzung machen? Zum beispiel: mach's ! (Mach das!) ?

Comment: Das ist wircklick die lezte.

Comment: Ja. "Mach(e) es!" --> "Mach's". Aber fuer mich erscheint "Mach's!" als ein weniger starker Befehl als "Mach(e) es!" Aehnlich mit "Tu(e) es!" --> "Tu(e)'s"

Comment: Zu deinem letzten Absatz: Was du schreibst, ist tatsächlich kein Dialekt. Was tatsächlich Dialekt ist, ist die Verkürzung von "Sie" wie in *zwei Semmeln? Nehmen's doch drei, dann ham's eine mehr*